# Force run of specific method

Tags: python, python-3.x, method-chaining

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase the title. Will change it if it doesn't make sense..

I recently came across method chaining and I really enjoy using it to accomplish some tasks.

Then I noticed I was calling one particular method at the end of every method and I was thinking if it's possible to force the execution of this method once the end of the chain is reached?

In fact, regardless of chaining, is it possible to do something like this with just normal class methods?

So for example:

```
class Alphabet:

    def _use_me(self):
        pass

    def a(self):
        # do some stuff
        self._use_me()
        return self

    def b(self):
        # do some stuff
        self._use_me()
        return self

    def c(self):
        # do some stuff
        self._use_me()
        return self
```

I was wondering that instead of at the end of every method to call `self._use_me()`, if it's possible to just run `self._use_me()` by default?

Maybe I am even thinking of it wrong and should change the implementation? Suggestions are welcome.

I can't find anything regarding this - but that could just be due to lack of knowledge and not using the correct search parameters on Google.

Comment: you could use a decorator or a with sentence

Comment: yes, take a look at decorator functions.

Comment: Oh yes, I remember a while ago I saw something about decorators and I had obviously forgotten about that.. Also something I can look into, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) come to mind:

```
class Alphabet:

    def __init__(self):
        return 
    
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self._use_me()
        print('exit')

    
    def _use_me(self):
        print('calling _use_me')

    def a(self):
        print('a')

    def b(self):
        print('b')

    def c(self):
        print('c')

# calling it:
with Alphabet() as a:
    a.a()
```

Comment: Instead of having one more line in each method you need to add one more line each time you call it. Doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you use can achieve this functionality using a decorator. A decorator to decorate any/all of your functions.

Try this code:

```
def use_me(func):
    def wrapper(self):

        # Do some stuff, before the function
        
        func(self)

        # Do some stuff, after the function
        print("called use_me")

    return wrapper

class Alphabet:
    
    @use_me
    def a(self):
        # do some stuff
        print('calling A')

    @use_me
    def b(self):
        # do some stuff
        print('calling B')
        return self

    @use_me
    def c(self):
        # do some stuff
        print('calling B')
        return self
```

This is how it works:

```
a = Alphabet()

a.a()
# calling A
# called use_me

a.b()
# calling B
# called use_me

a.c()
# calling C
# called use_me
```

Comment: This also seems to be a valid solution but @warped's answer is a better solution IMO since it's just one method at the top of class doing the work and if I use a decorator, I'd essentially be doing the same thing: adding the same line to every method in the class.

Thank you for the answer though, I'd probably find a use for this at some point :)

Comment: This is more suitable if you only want the method to be called at the end of a subset of methods implemented in your class. The other approach calls it at the end of *every* method.

Comment: Just coming back to this post now because I'm implementing some decorators and I now see as well that the above solution wouldn't have worked anyway for my use case. I specifically needed the method to be within in the class and not outside so that I could access other class members within that method. Nevertheless, it was still a useful answer!